# creating new lucene index no class found error

Tags: java, lucene, noclassdeffounderror

i'm using lucene 4.0 and i want to create a new `indexWriter` in this way:

```
IndexWriter index = LuceneUtils.createIndexWriter(indexPath, true);
```

(it worked using lucene 3.6)
where `indexPath` is a `String` with the path of the index. I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/SimpleAnalyzer
at lucene.IndexCreator.<init>(IndexCreator.java:25)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 2 more
```

i have read that i need to add `lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar` to the project besides `lucene-core-4.0.0.jar`, but i get the same error.
as a matter of fact the path of `SimpleAnalyzer.class` inside `lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar` is not `org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer` but `org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have a 3.6 jar in your class path. Can you verify that an older version isn't being pulled in, possibly by transitive dependencies?

Comment: mvn dependency:tree will do the job if Maven is used.

Comment: Or `gradle dependencies` if Gradle is used.